# Mandrill- how to remove "mailed by mandrill app"

Tags: mandrill

I was able to remove `via asdfklsdj@ksjl.com`  etc from next to my email address that would appear to receiver of message from my email.

But if i expand i still see mailed by mandrill app. Is there a way to have to removed...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Return-Path address for your emails is where things like bounces and other delivery events are sent. It's also known as the "envelope-from" or MAIL FROM address. (For Gmail users, the `mailed-by` header typically is generated from this address). You can customize the Return-Path domain used for your emails to change what's shown in Gmail. Instructions for this can be found in the [Mandrill KB](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/25241243-Can-I-customize-the-Return-Path-bounce-address-used-for-my-emails-).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way to remove the "mailed by" in gmail. Mandrill must identify as the sending party and gmail is allowed to show it.

The best you can do is remove the 'via' using proper DKIM/SPF setup -- which it looks like you're already doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove mandrillapp.com. Just follow the below steps.

Save the Return Path Domain in Mandrill
Go to Settings.
Choose Tracking & Return Path Domains.
Enter your subdomain and click Add.
Click Test DNS Settings to verify the settings for the subdomain you've added.

After that Go to Sending Default in Settings.
Set Return Path Domain as newly added Sub Domina.
Save these settings.

After that in header section you 'll see mailled-by value with the name of your subdomain.